# MIPS: Selective copying from one string to another error

Tags: mips

I have tried to write a program in MIPS that takes a string and prints a result with only characters (assuming that the string is alphanumerical). It works perfectly for strings of size < 4, but when a 4th character occurs, it goes into infinite loop.

```
.data
    string: .word 10
.data
    result: .word 10
.data
    message1: .asciiz "number\n"
.data
    message2: .asciiz "letter "
.data
    message3: .asciiz "finished loop\n"


.text
    main:
        li $v0 8    # take input as string
        la $a0 string   # store it in "string"
        la $a1 10   # size of "string" is at most 10
        syscall
        la $s0 string   # save address of "string" to s0
        la $s1 result   # save address of "result" to s1


        Loop:
            li $t0 10   # set t0 as '/n'
            lb $t1 ($s0)    # load character that we are currently checking
            beq $t0 $t1 Exit    # check if we are at the end of the string


            li $t0 64   # set t0 to 64 to check if it is a letter (character that we are now checking must be greater than 64)
            slt $t2 $t0 $t1 # t2 will store the result of comparison ($t1 - character)
            li $t0 0    # set t0 to 0 to check the result of comparison
            beq $t2 $t0 Increment # if 64 > ch, then we must just proceed
            li $v0 4
            la $a0 message2 # print message that it is a character
            syscall
            sb $t1 ($s1)    # copy this character into our "result"
            addi $s1 $s1 1  # increment the address of "result"

        Increment:
            li $v0 4
            la $a0 message1 # print message that it is a number
            syscall
            addi $s0 $s0 1  # increment the address of "string" to proceed in loop
            j Loop

        Exit:
            li $t0 10
            sb $t0 ($s1)    # add endline character to "result"
            addi $s1 $s1 1
            li $t0 0
            sb $t0 ($s1)    # add null character to "result"
            li $v0 4
            la $a0 message3 # print message that the loop has finished
            syscall
            li $v0 4
            la $a0 result   # print result
            syscall
            jr $ra
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try stepping through it in a debugger (like SPIM).

Comment: at 4th character it stays at the same character, but debugger shows that it is trying to increment the address

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without stepping through myself, but here's an idea: use the power of "i", that is, Immediate mode. That way, you don't have to worry about whether a register value isn't quite what you expected. Also, use the special `$zero` register instead of loading a register with zero. So change this:

```
        li $t0 64   # set t0 to 64 to check if it is a letter (character that we are now checking must be greater than 64)
        slt $t2 $t0 $t1 # t2 will store the result of comparison ($t1 - character)
        li $t0 0    # set t0 to 0 to check the result of comparison
        beq $t2 $t0 Increment # if 64 > ch, then we must just proceed
```

to this:

```
        slti $t2, $t1, 'A' # A little different: set $t2 if $t1 < 65 ('A')
        bne $t2, $zero Increment # branch if $t1 < 'A'
```

Maybe by eliminating registers in favor of immediates, you can find the glitch that's causing you to go into a loop.

Also, a couple of other possible glitch sources:

- You're looking for `'\n'` to terminate the string, but I'm not sure you can guarantee that the syscall will add \n if the input is a full 10 characters. Perhaps you should also/instead check for the zero-terminator byte value.
- You've defined `string` and `result` as 10 words, but you're actually storing bytes in them. That shouldn't be a problem - you've allocated 40 bytes instead of 10. But if you ever go back and change those to `byte`, be sure to allow for that trailing `\0` (and `\n`).

Sorry I can't be more specific, but hope that points you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks for feedback, can you explain a bit or give a link to a "byte" and "allowing for that trailing '\0' and '\n' "?

Comment: byte even causes more problems

Comment: If you use `.word 10`, you're allocating 10 words. Each word is 4 bytes. So I would definitely expect you to have more problems if you switch to `.byte` without making other changes. 10 bytes read from the syscall would be at least 11 bytes in your buffer: if the user enters `ABCDEFGHIJ`, the string will be `ABCDEFGHIJ\0` with a trailing `nul`. If you only allocated 10 bytes, the `nul` overwrites the first byte of the next memory location. Also, if you only look for `\n`, in that case, you'll read bytes way past your buffer.